# Swap tables google bigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can I swap 2 tables in the same structure in Google bigQuery?
Is there any different if the tables are partitioned or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "swap"?

Comment: The command in SQL Server would be SWITCH but I can't find an equivalent for BigQuery.

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understood your question: you can copy tableA to tableTemp; tableB to tableA with overwrites; tableTemp to tableB with overwrites and finally delete tableTemp

Copy is free in BigQuery. See more about Renaming / Copy and Managing Tables in general here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#renaming_a_table

Comment: copy is free, but sometimes you need an atomic swap or move to avoid temporary unavailable tables